# Is there a DAW that can export a short perfect loop to a 8 hours long mp3 for OSX?

Tags: daw, export, looping

Is there a DAW that can export a short perfect loop to a 8 hours long wav or mp3 for OSX?
I know Goldwave can do that but I can't find a correspoding app for Osx.
The only way I can do that in Pro Tools is to duplicate the loop until reaches 8 hours long and then consolidate the file as there is no way to export a file that long in Pro Tools. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

So finally Reaper can do that. I looks that you can export unlimited duration files which is not possible with any other DAW I tried as Pro Tools, Logic Pro or Ableton Live.